# strftime function pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to strip the time out of the date when the dataframe writes to Excel, but have been unsuccessful.

The weird thing is, I am able to manipulate the dataframe by using the lambda and striptime function below, and can see it the function is working by my `print df6`.

However, for some reason when I open the Excel file it shows in the format `%m%d%y: 12:00am`. I would like to just have the date show. Ideas?

Here is my code:

```python
df6 = df
workbook = writer.book
df6.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Frogs', startrow= 4, index=False)
df6['ASOFDATE'] = df6['ASOFDATE'].apply(lambda x:x.date().strftime('%d%m%y'))
worksheet = writer.sheets['Frogs']
format5 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})
#format6= workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mmm d yyyy'})
#worksheet.set_column('A:A', 18, format6)
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format5)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 18, format5)
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 18, format5)
now = datetime.now()
date= dt.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
link_format = workbook.add_format({'color': 'black', 'bold': 1})
nrows = df6.shape[0]
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Chart4', link_format) 
worksheet.write(1, 0, 'Frogs',link_format) 
#Multiply dataframe by 100 to get out of decimals (this method is used when dates are in the picture)
df6[df6.columns[np.all(df6.gt(0) & df6.lt(1),axis=0)]] *= 100
print df6
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

strftime is creating a textual representation of a datetime value which later is formatted and displayed by Excel according to its formatting templates. We could change this formatting template using `date_format` parameter in our ExcelWriter constructor e.g.:`writer = pandas.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter", date_format="ddmmyyyy")`. I've slightly modified your sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ASOFDATE'] = [datetime.datetime.now() for x in xrange(3)]
for i in xrange(3):
    df[i] = [1,2,3]
df6 = df
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', date_format="ddmmyyyy")
workbook = writer.book
df6.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Frogs', startrow= 4, index=False)
worksheet = writer.sheets['Frogs']
format5 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format5)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 18, format5)
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 18, format5)
link_format = workbook.add_format({'color': 'black', 'bold': 1})
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Chart4', link_format)
worksheet.write(1, 0, 'Frogs',link_format)
writer.save()
```

This code produces a file which has date values formatted according to the specified template.

Comment: @nullop- thanks for the response. Unfortunately this did not work. Excel is writing col A as  ;2016-01-31 00:00:00'

Comment: I've updated my comment with code sample. Could you check if it works for you? If you have any strftime calls applied to your date values, you probably have to remove them.

Comment: Ah i see what might be the problem. I have the strtime function in there because I am using it for something un related- having excel write the current date below the data frame.. Her eis the code. date= dt.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")      nrows = df5.shape[0]      worksheet.write(nrows + 8, 0, 'Data as of ' + date, link_format)